# Desktop screen is completely black, taskbar not showing on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde

The rest of my system works fine, I can open apps using alt+f2 and navigate with latte dock. But the taskbar itself doesn't show and the desktop is completely black, no widgets or apps/files can be seen. Sometimes it flashes for a second. I've tried running `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart plasmashell` which gave me the error `"Application plasmashell could not be found using service org.kde.plasmashell and path /MainApplication."`

I've also tried running `nohup kstart5 plasmashell` and `kstart5 plasmashell`, which both just flash the desktop and taskbar

Finally, I tried running `systemctl --user restart plasma-plasmashell.service` which gives me the error `Failed to restart plasma-plasmashell.service: Unit plasma-plasmashell.service not found`

I guess plasmashell isn't running but running it only works for a second? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my plasma and window style back to breeze, then ran `nohup kstart5 plasmashell`. That fixed my issue.